# how to fix SFINAE check for operator== existing, so that it works with std::pair

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have a simple SFINAE checker that checks a given type (`T`) if it has an `operator==` defined for it.

This generally works fairly well, but it does not work for `std::pair<>`.

I think I understand why it doesn't work - `std::pair<>` appears to unconditionally provide `operator==` support, even if the underlying types its a pair of do not.

I'm soliciting views on how to correct my SFINAE `operator==` checker, so that it works with `pair<>`

You can test this code online at https://onlinegdb.com/rmAQS7V091

But for completeness sake, its included here directly as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>       // needed for std::equal_to
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

namespace
{

  using namespace std;

    /**
     *  LIFTED -@todo add docs/reference
     *  from Stroustrup C++11 book - page 800
     */
  struct substitution_failure
  {
  };

    /**
     *  LIFTED -@todo add docs/reference
     *  from Stroustrup C++11 book - page 800
     */
  template < typename T > struct substitution_succeeded:true_type
  {
  };
  template <> struct substitution_succeeded <substitution_failure >:false_type
  {
  };

#define STROIKA_FOUNDATION_CONFIGURATION_DEFINE_HAS(NAME, XTEST)                                                                              \
    namespace Private_ {                                                                                                                          \
        template <typename T>                                                                                                                     \
        struct NAME##_result_impl {                                                                                                               \
            template <typename X>                                                                                                                 \
            static auto                                                     check (const X& x) -> decltype (XTEST);                               \
            static substitution_failure check (...);                                                          \
            using type = decltype (check (declval<T> ()));                                                                                        \
        };                                                                                                                                        \
    }                                                                                                                                             \
    template <typename T>                                                                                                                         \
    using NAME##_result = typename Private_::NAME##_result_impl<T>::type;                                                                         \
    template <typename T>                                                                                                                         \
    struct has_##NAME : integral_constant<bool, not is_same<NAME##_result<T>, substitution_failure>::value> { \
    };                                                                                                                                            \
    template <typename ITERABLE>                                                                                                                  \
    constexpr bool Has##NAME##_v = has_##NAME<ITERABLE>::value;


  STROIKA_FOUNDATION_CONFIGURATION_DEFINE_HAS (eq, (x == x));   // SEE https://stroika.atlassian.net/browse/STK-749
  STROIKA_FOUNDATION_CONFIGURATION_DEFINE_HAS (equal_to, (static_cast<bool> (std::equal_to<X>{}(x, x))));


  class SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators
  {
  public:
    SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators (size_t v);
    SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators (const
                       SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators
                       & f);
     ~SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators ();

    size_t GetValue () const;
    static size_t GetTotalLiveCount ();

    //explicit operator size_t () const { return fValue; }

    SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators operator+ (const
                             SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators
                             & rhs) const
    {
      return SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators (fValue + rhs.fValue);
    }

  private:
      size_t fValue;
    int fConstructed;
    static size_t sTotalLiveObjects;
  };


  static_assert (!has_eq < SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators >::value);

  using PAIR_ =
    std::pair < SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators,
    SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators >;
  static_assert (!has_eq < PAIR_ >::value);     /// THIS IS WHAT FAILS


}

int
main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [kenash0625](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16746390/kenash0625) correctly noted, you need a specialization for `std::pair` to manually implement checks that `std::pair` itself does not do. However, at this point, I suggest simplifying your implementation with C++17 and without macros:

```
template<
    template<typename...> typename Detector, 
    typename T, 
    typename SFINAE = void>
constexpr inline bool is_detected_v = false; 

template<
    template<typename...> typename Detector, 
    typename T>
constexpr inline bool is_detected_v<
    Detector, T, std::void_t<Detector<T>>> = true;
```

We can now implement `has_eq` like this:

```
template<typename T>
using has_eq_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<T>());

static_assert(is_detected_v<has_eq_t, std::pair<int, int>>);
```

We can also write a helper, whose first purpose is to increase code expressiveness:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr inline bool has_eq_v = is_detected_v<has_eq_t, T>;

static_assert( ! has_eq_v<SimpleClassWithoutComparisonOperators>);
```

Although the original issue has not been fixed yet, the second purpose of this helper is where we can implement some ad hoc checks for `std::pair`. Let's add the specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr inline bool has_eq_v<std::pair<T, U>> = has_eq_v<T> && has_eq_v<U>;
```

Here we can add more and more specializations for such specific cases:

```
template<typename... Ts>
constexpr inline bool has_eq_v<std::tuple<Ts...>> = (has_eq_v<Ts> && ...);
```

[Check the code now](https://godbolt.org/z/MWKdsM79c):

```
static_assert ( ! has_eq_v<PAIR_>);
```

Further reading:

- You should read about the [Detection Idioms](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000040852065/en), this [is a more flexible implementation of my `is_detected_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)
- C++20 concepts allow us to make our implementation way simpler. I think the concepts are the main reason why we don't have the `std::is_detected` in standard library. It just isn't needed with concepts.

Comment: This is a GREAT answer! Thank you! I ESPECIALLY like your going above and beyond and helping me replace that old macro stuff with your is_detected_v approach! And your links about how to improve this and concepts. I haven't yet had a chance to read up on all that but look forward to it.

Comment: One SLIGHT detect with this answer (really all the answers so far) - is with equal_to. It has the same problem as pair<> - defining operator() even if the underling == isn't there. With the same possible workaround - a partial template specialization. HOWEVER - what if someone did NOT define operator== for T, but DID themseleves specailize equal_to<T>? This appears allowed by C++, and then this checking code doesn't work (ignores the specialization).

Comment: Existing practice in the standard library (for standard library template specializations) is to treat such behavior as completely undefined. This removes from the standard any responsibility of the library for the behavior caused by such code. In many other libraries, this is like an (un)written contract between the user and the library — you (as a library user) just shouldn't do bad things like this

Answer (score 2):

To fix `std::pair` case, you might specialize your traits for it:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct has_eq<std::pair<T1, T2>> :
    integral_constant<bool, has_eq<T1>::value && has_eq<T1>::value>
{};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/sXvM1oyIH)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my naive fix: add two lines of code to `#define`,

```
  template <typename X>   \
            static substitution_failure check (std::pair<X,X>); \
```

altogether:

```
#define STROIKA_FOUNDATION_CONFIGURATION_DEFINE_HAS(NAME, XTEST)                                                                              \
    namespace Private_ {                                                                                                                          \
        template <typename T>                                                                                                                     \
        struct NAME##_result_impl {                                                                                                               \
            template <typename X>                                                                                                                 \
            static auto                                                     check (const X& x) -> decltype (XTEST);                               \
            static substitution_failure check (...);                                                          \
            template <typename X>   \
            static substitution_failure check (std::pair<X,X>); \
            using type = decltype (check (declval<T> ()));                                                                                        \
        };                                                                                                                                        \
    }                                                                                                                                             \
    template <typename T>                                                                                                                         \
    using NAME##_result = typename Private_::NAME##_result_impl<T>::type;                                                                         \
    template <typename T>                                                                                                                         \
    struct has_##NAME : integral_constant<bool, not is_same<NAME##_result<T>, substitution_failure>::value> { \
    };                                                                                                                                            \
    template <typename ITERABLE>                                                                                                                  \
    constexpr bool Has##NAME##_v = has_##NAME<ITERABLE>::value;
```

Comment: That will unconditionally reject pair, whereas OP want to reject pair only if first_type or second_type are not comparable.

Comment: @Jarod42  thanks,your answer is clear than mine,I learned a lot